# addEventListener : how to limit a callback function?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

Actually i want to give button a functionality such that it is clickable for certain times only, how can i do it?
also how can i pass a user defined input/parameter to callback function of addEventListener.

Comment: Use a variable to store how many times the button was clicked, then increment that variable on every click.

Comment: Hi @prph8 try to edit your question and add some code snippet, it will help to answer you better.

Answer (score 0):

As Wai, You can use a global variable in JS, or if using a framework then store that variable in state and in the callback function verify if it's within the limit or otherwise increment and execute the function, below is a sample implementation.

```
const countsClicked = 0;
const button = document.getElementById('my-button');
button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (countsClicked >= 5) {
    return;
  }
  //execute 
  ++countsClicked;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did that

```
<script>
    var count = 0;

    document.getElementById("your_id").addEventListener("click", () => {
      if (count < 10) {
        count++;
        console.log("Clicked");
      }
    });
</script>
```